# SQL - select data based on one specific input value or all if no input value

Tags: sql

I am trying to retrieve data using an input variable that is a Customer code. If a user enters the customer code, the query retrieves that customers data, but if the user leaves the customer code blank, I want to retrieve all customers data.  Below is the code where I can retrieve data based on the customer code input in '3_customer' but I can't figure out how to do this IF-THEN-ELSE type of query I need to get data for all customers if the input variable is left blank.

Thanks, 
Don

```
SELECT 
    open_item.order_id order_id,
    convert(varchar(10),orders.ordered_date,101) order_date,
    orders.revenue_code_id,
    orders.operations_user,
    open_item.customer_id cust_no,
    customer.name cust_name,
    convert(varchar(10),open_item.gl_date,101) adjust_date,
    open_item.amount amount,
    open_item.record_type type,
    open_item.ar_reason_code_id,
    ar_reason_code.descr reason
FROM 
    open_item
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    customer ON customer.id = open_item.customer_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ar_reason_code ON open_item.ar_reason_code_id = ar_reason_code.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    orders ON orders.id = open_item.order_id 
WHERE 
    open_item.gl_date >= $1_sdate$ AND 
    open_item.gl_date <= $2_edate$ AND
    open_item.source = 'C' AND 
    open_item.record_type = 'C' AND
    open_item.customer_id = $3_customer$
```

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: @Ruslan: Looks like SQL Server

Comment: So can customer_ID be "Blank" /empty set instead of NULL?or could there be  non-display character in customer.id?

Comment: @xQbert: There doesn't appear to be any non-display characters in the input field of customer.id.  The customer_id field cannot be blank in the table.

Comment: so is empty set '' passed in on $3_customer$?  I was expecting null

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to:

```
open_item.customer_id = coalesce($3_customer$, open_item.customer_ID)
```

assuming $3_customer$ will be NULL

so $3_customer$ must not be null so then use a case

```
open_item.customer_id = case when $3_customer$ = '' 
                             then open_item.customer_ID else $3_customer$
```

coalesce takes the first non-null value in a series  in essence this will always return TRUE when the customer parameter is null.  It does this because it compares the same values thus always equaling; otherwise this will filter for the specific $3_customer$ provided

Comment: Unless `customer_id` can be null for some reason and the equality test fails. Doesn't seem to apply in this case though.

Comment: Agreed.  if NULL holds special meaning for customer_Id then this will not be a proper solution.

Comment: This didn't work.  The only way I've been able to get all customers to list is to completely eliminate any reference to customer_id in the WHERE statement, then it selects all customers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to slightly change the `WHERE` clause for the customer condition from this:

```
and open_item.customer_id = $3_customer$
```

to something like this: (The below code comes with the assumption that `$3_customer$` is getting inserted into the query string, and will be set to `NULL` if empty)

```
and ($3_customer$ IS NULL OR open_item.customer_id = $3_customer$)
```

Comment: Logically `A and not B or B` is equivalent to `A or B`. But it's possible the optimizer can use the extra info and short-circuit.

Comment: @shawnt00 Right! Thanks for noticing. Adjusted.

Comment: This didn't work.  The only way I've been able to get all customers to list is to completely eliminate any reference to customer_id in the WHERE statement, then it selects all customers.